# yii2 "Unable to resolve the request" with ActiveController

Tags: php, rest, yii2

I have a simple Yii2 REST application. See:

[image]

As you can see, there is only one model `Category`, and there is only one controller `CategoryController`

`Category`:

```
<?php

namespace api\models;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "{{%category}}".
 *
 * @property int $id
 * @property string $slug
 * @property string $title
 * @property int $enabled
 *
 */
class Category extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return '{{%category}}';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ['enabled', 'default', 'value' => 0],
            [['title'], 'required'],
            [['enabled'], 'integer'],
            [['slug', 'title'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
            [['slug'], 'unique'],
        ];
    }
}
```

`CategoryController`:

```
<?php

namespace api\controllers;

use yii\rest\ActiveController;

/**
 * Class CategoryController
 *
 * @package api\controllers
 */
class CategoryController extends ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass = 'api\models\Category';

}
```

Then I will pin here my configuration for the application:

`config/main.php`

```
<?php
$params = array_merge(
    require __DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params-local.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/params.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/params-local.php'
);

return [
    'id' => 'app-api',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'language' => 'ru-RU',
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'controllerNamespace' => 'api\controllers',
    'components' => [
        'request' => [
            'parsers' => [
                'application/json' => 'yii\web\JsonParser',
            ]
        ],
        'response' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\Response',
            'format' => 'json'
        ],
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
            'identityCookie' => ['name' => '_identity-frontend', 'httpOnly' => true],
        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'enableStrictParsing' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
                    'controller' => 'category',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];
```

How I run it? Simple. Just with the help of `$ php -S localhost:8900` inside the `web` directory.

But when I visit the URL: `localhost:8900/categories` I see the following:

> {"name":"Not Found","message":"Page not found.","code":0,"status":404,"type":"yii\web\NotFoundHttpException","previous":{"name":"Invalid Route","message":"Unable to resolve the request \"category/index\".","code":0,"type":"yii\base\InvalidRouteException"}}

What does it mean? I suppose that Yii makes the following things.

- It tries to process `/categories` request (but Yii can't do that by some unknown for me reason)
- Then the framework redirects me on the 404 functional. It's the reason why we can see here `"name":"Not Found","message":"Page not found.","code":0,"status":404,"type":"yii\\web\\NotFoundHttpException",`

But the reason of `{"name":"Invalid Route","message":"Unable to resolve the request \"category/index\".","code":0,"type":"yii\\base\\InvalidRouteException"}` is unknown for me.

All of this is strange behavior. I'm just trying to follow along this official [guide](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/rest-quick-start)
What is wrong for my configuration?

#### Update

I have dived deeper(directly inside the entrails of the framework).

I found, that the crash is happening here :

```
   /**
     * Creates a controller based on the given controller ID.
     *
     * The controller ID is relative to this module. The controller class
     * should be namespaced under [[controllerNamespace]].
     *
     * Note that this method does not check [[modules]] or [[controllerMap]].
     *
     * @param string $id the controller ID.
     * @return Controller|null the newly created controller instance, or `null` if the controller ID is invalid.
     * @throws InvalidConfigException if the controller class and its file name do not match.
     * This exception is only thrown when in debug mode.
     */
    public function createControllerByID($id)
    {
        $pos = strrpos($id, '/');
        if ($pos === false) {
            $prefix = '';
            $className = $id;
        } else {
            $prefix = substr($id, 0, $pos + 1);
            $className = substr($id, $pos + 1);
        }

        if ($this->isIncorrectClassNameOrPrefix($className, $prefix)) {
            return null;
        }

        $className = preg_replace_callback('%-([a-z0-9_])%i', function ($matches) {
                return ucfirst($matches[1]);
            }, ucfirst($className)) . 'Controller';
        $className = ltrim($this->controllerNamespace . '\\' . str_replace('/', '\\', $prefix) . $className, '\\');
        // THE PROBLEM IS HERE !!! WITH THE  !class_exists($className)
        if (strpos($className, '-') !== false || !class_exists($className)) {
            return null;
        }

        if (is_subclass_of($className, 'yii\base\Controller')) {
            $controller = Yii::createObject($className, [$id, $this]);
            return get_class($controller) === $className ? $controller : null;
        } elseif (YII_DEBUG) {
            throw new InvalidConfigException('Controller class must extend from \\yii\\base\\Controller.');
        }

        return null;
    }
```

the `!class_exists($className)` takes this string as argument `"api\controllers\CategoryController"` 
and returns `true`. The condition works, and I have `null` as result.

What is happening then? The following:

```
    /**
     * Runs a controller action specified by a route.
     * This method parses the specified route and creates the corresponding child module(s), controller and action
     * instances. It then calls [[Controller::runAction()]] to run the action with the given parameters.
     * If the route is empty, the method will use [[defaultRoute]].
     * @param string $route the route that specifies the action.
     * @param array $params the parameters to be passed to the action
     * @return mixed the result of the action.
     * @throws InvalidRouteException if the requested route cannot be resolved into an action successfully.
     */
    public function runAction($route, $params = [])
    {
        $parts = $this->createController($route);
        // $parts IS NULL !!!!!!!!!!
        if (is_array($parts)) {
            /* @var $controller Controller */
            list($controller, $actionID) = $parts;
            $oldController = Yii::$app->controller;
            Yii::$app->controller = $controller;
            $result = $controller->runAction($actionID, $params);
            if ($oldController !== null) {
                Yii::$app->controller = $oldController;
            }

            return $result;
        }

        $id = $this->getUniqueId();
        throw new InvalidRouteException('Unable to resolve the request "' . ($id === '' ? $route : $id . '/' . $route) . '".');
    }
```

And I see the familiar exception `InvalidRouteException`. Any ideas?

Comment: Does it work when you set `enableStrictParsing` to `false`?

Comment: You need to set the index method on `CategoryController`

Comment: @Bizley tried with `enableStrictParsing` and without it. No effect.

Answer (score 2):

Ok. The answer is simple. If you are developing new one application with the help of copy and paste from another one (like me), don't forget to update `common/config/bootstrap.php` and add new one alias. My new application's name is `api`. It means my `bootstrap.php` is:

```
<?php
Yii::setAlias('@common', dirname(__DIR__));
Yii::setAlias('@frontend', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/frontend');
Yii::setAlias('@backend', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/backend');
Yii::setAlias('@console', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/console');
Yii::setAlias('@api', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/api'); // <- new application!!!
```

P.S. I use advanced template. Thank you for reading)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify an index method on the `CategoryController`.

IE:

```php
public function actionIndex()    
{
     return $this->render('index');
}
```

And offcourse you need to add the template for this method or

Comment: Thank you, but I already have tried it. Without any success(( And I would like to use embedded in the ActiveController's actions.  It's described here https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/rest-quick-start#trying-it-out

Comment: i am not familiar with yii, but the basepath is set to `__dir__` which is the config dir, is this correct?

Comment: after some further research, it appears your directory structure does not seem to be correct, you need to specify a backend folder. source : https://github.com/samdark/yii2-shop/tree/master/backend

Comment: It works nice for other kinds of applications. For example it works for `frontend` application (client website), `backend` application (admin website) I copied and paste it from the Yii Advanced Template. I don't think that there is any difference between this application kinds (I mean configuration). At least, I never seen something about it in the Yii guides.

Comment: In that case it might be a permission problem, if on linux `sudo chown -R 777 {path to your app}` edit: NEVER DO THIS ON PRODUCTION PLS

Comment: `chmod` don't give any affect ((

Comment: Can you search the entire codebase (including vendor) for any place the exception `invalidRouteException` is being thrown, that might clarify the condition for why it is showing up

Comment: i noticed you used `\yii\db\ActiveRecord` in you model, but dont include it in the php file , can this be the issue?

Comment: to search the `invalidRouteException` is good idea. I have already found this place. Now I'm trying to understand why this method (I mean, the method where `invalidRouteException` used) throws the exception.

Comment: about `\yii\db\ActiveRecord` it's not a problem because I have specified whole qualification name. And it's just an extends. I think if it is the reason, I would see something like runtime exception.

Comment: is it by any chance inside a try/catch block, if this is the case, throw the exception caught instead of letting the code throw the `invalidRouteException`

Comment: I'm sorry i can't help further i have to go to my birthday party. Godspeed brother,

Comment: it's ok)) Thank you bro)) I feel, I'm pretty close to the true))

Comment: I have updated my question if you're still interesting new details))